# Inverse Laplace transform seems to be always vanishing but it couldn't!

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, laplace-transform, contour-integration, residue-calculus

Let's consider $x\in (0,1)$ and the distribution $p(x)=\lambda x^\lambda$, $\lambda>0$. I would like to find the pdf of the sum. The characteristic function of the $N$ sum reads:
\begin{equation}
\phi_{S_N}=(\lambda s^{-\lambda}[\Gamma(\lambda)-\Gamma(\lambda,s)])^N
\end{equation} 
To compute the inverse Laplace transform I set $\lambda N\in \mathcal N$ (i.e if $\lambda=0.1$ I use only $N=10,20,..$) and I use the Residue theorem. But this give me ALWAYS ZERO since the only pole is in $s=0$ and $\Gamma(\lambda,0)=\Gamma(\lambda)$. Is this CORRECT? I have also decomposed each term using the Binomial theorem and the result is always vanishing. Since this defines a pdf it couldn't be vanishing everywhere! Someone see the error ?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are ignoring the effect of the branch point at $s=0$ due to the $s^{-\lambda}$ behavior.  This is true despite the pole.  To illustrate, let's expand out the binomial and look at the first term, the constant. The ILT in this case is

$$\frac{\Gamma(\lambda)^N}{i 2 \pi} \int_{c-i \infty}^{c+ i \infty} ds \, s^{-\lambda} e^{s t} $$

To evaluate this, we consider a Bromwich contour $C$ to the left of the line $\operatorname{Re}{z}=c$.  However, we take the negative real axis to be a branch cut, so we actually have separate circular arcs of radius $R$, divided by separate traversals above and below the negative real axis and a circular arc about the origin of radius $\epsilon$.  The integral about this contour,

$$\oint_C dz \, z^{-\lambda} e^{t z}$$

is equal to

$$\int_{c-i R}^{c+i R} ds \, s^{-\lambda} e^{s t} + i R^{1-\lambda} \int_{\pi/2}^{\pi} d\theta \, e^{i (1-\lambda) \theta} e^{t R e^{i \theta}} \\ + e^{i \pi} \int_R^{\epsilon} dx \, e^{-i \lambda \pi}  x^{-\lambda} e^{-t x}+i \epsilon^{1-\lambda} \int_{\pi}^{-\pi} d\phi \, e^{i (1-\lambda)\phi} e^{t \epsilon e^{i \phi}}\\+ e^{-i \pi} \int_{\epsilon}^R dx \, e^{i \lambda \pi} x^{-\lambda} e^{-t x}+i R^{1-\lambda} \int_{\pi}^{3 \pi/2} d\theta \, e^{i (1-\lambda) \theta} e^{t R e^{i \theta}}$$

We can show that the second and sixth integrals vanish as $R \to \infty$.  For example, the magnitude of the second integral is bounded by

$$R^{1-\lambda} \int_0^{\pi/2} d\theta \, e^{-t R \sin{\theta}} \le R^{1-\lambda} \int_0^{\pi/2} d\theta \, e^{-2 t R \theta/\pi} \le \frac{\pi}{2 t R^{\lambda}}$$

which vanishes because $\lambda \gt 0$.

We can also see that the fourth integral vanishes as $\epsilon \to 0$ because $\lambda \lt 1$.

In these limits, then, we are left with, as the contour integral,

$$\int_{c-i \infty}^{c+i \infty} ds \, s^{-\lambda} e^{s t} + \left ( e^{-i \lambda \pi} - e^{i \lambda \pi} \right ) \int_0^{\infty} dx \, x^{-\lambda} e^{-t x} $$

By Cauchy's theorem, the contour integral is zero because there are no poles inside the contour $C$.  Thus, we may now write down the ILT:

$$\frac{\Gamma(\lambda)^N}{i 2 \pi}\int_{c-i \infty}^{c+i \infty} ds \, s^{-\lambda} e^{s t} = \frac{t^{-(1-\lambda)}}{\pi} \Gamma(\lambda)^N \Gamma(1-\lambda) \sin{\pi \lambda} = \Gamma(\lambda)^{N-1} t^{-(1-\lambda)}$$

Of course, in reality, you have to contend with all of the other terms involving the upper incomplete Gamma, or the binomial taken as a whole.  But what I did should outline for you the approach necessary to compute the ILT here.

Comment: SUPER!! Only one question more: how did you obtain the minus sign when computing the magnitude? Since for the second integral we have: $\int_{\pi/2}^\pi e^{t R sin(\phi)}$... For the rest it is just super well explained thanks!

Comment: @ToTo10: $$\cos{\left ( \theta+\frac{\pi}{2} \right )} = -\sin{\theta}$$

Comment: @ToTo10: it's $t R \cos{\theta}$, not $t R \sin{\theta}$.

Comment: I just noticed that I have to compute $\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}s^{-\lambda N}e^{t s}$ and not $\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}s^{-\lambda }e^{t s}$. This is a big problem since we cannot impose $\lambda N<1$ and therefore the fourth integral is not vanishing.. This is a huge problem hmmm

Comment: @ToTo10: in that case, you have to figure out the multiplicity of the pole on top of the branch point.  It should be clear that you will end up taking derivatives of the result I derived to get the higher-order answers.